# Setting devise admin role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, devise

Trying to assign myself as an admin user for my rails app. I carried out option 2 from the devise wiki guide and successfully added an admin column to my user table. I am now wondering how to actually change my role from false to true. Should I simply do it through IRB? via the rails console? or rails db, through Postgres environment? sorry for the newb question.

*steps so far*

**1 .generated a migration**

```
rails generate migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean
```

**2 .editted migration then ran rake db:migrate**

```
 class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
   end

   def self.down
    remove_column :users, :admin
   end
 end
```

**UPDATE**

I simply did this through rails console. Since I already created an account through the user interface, I could simply set the boolean value of true through rails console like so -

```
 2.0.0p353 :014 > User.connection
 2.0.0p353 :014 > user = User.first
 2.0.0p353 :014 > user.admin = true
 2.0.0p353 :014 > user.save
```

Please comment or correct any issues. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't be possible by `irb` that I know of, unless you loaded your Rails environment, like the Rails console does. You could do it several ways (an SQL query, for example), but I tend to do things like this via the console because it calls the ActiveRecord [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) when a model changes, and this isn't the case with SQL, for example.